# How to grey out entry items in a ListPreference

Tags: android

I have a `PreferenceActivity` where 3 `ListPreferences` are present.

Each `ListPreference` has some entries(2 or 3).

I want to show only 1 entry highlighted and the rest greyed out in one of the `ListPreference`.

What changes do I need to do in `PreferenceActivity` if I change ListPreference to some `CustomeListPreference`?

Where do I start? Can anybody help me figure out what to do?

Answer (score 5):

Since `ListPreference` inherts `Preference` you should be able to first set [`setShouldDisableView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setShouldDisableView%28boolean%29) to true.  Then, set [`setEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) to false.  This should make the item appear disabled (grey) and not clickable.

Comment: but what I want to grey out is the one of the entries in ListPreference , not the ListPreference itself.

Comment: hi, let me elaborate, i have 3 list preferences in preferenceACTIVITY, EG: COLORS,Flowers,DAYS  and one COLORS has RED,BLUE,YELLOW.I want to grey out blue n yellow in the COLORS LIstPreference. can you  please provide some help ?